# Multiple Optional Params in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I'm using React Router v5.

I've got a situation where I need to support the following use case.

I've got React component that is accessed via `/project/1234`. However, I also need to access this same React component via both `/project/1234/hello` and `/project/1234/goodbye.` Again, all three of these routes need to navigate to the same React component.

The following code doesn't work since, as I understand it, if I navigate to `/project/1234/goodbye`, react-router will interpret this as me passing 'goodbye' as the value of the `:hello` param, so if I interrogate the params programmatically using react-router's `useParams()` hook itself, I'll have the wrong param values.

```
<Route
   path={'project/:context/:hello?/:goodbye?'}
   render={matchProps => <Project {...matchProps}/>}
/>
```

In other words, if navigate to `/project/1234/goodbye` and then do:

```
const params = useParams()
console.log(params.hello)
```

`params.hello` will return 'goodbye'

Similarly, this won't work, because using an array, `/project/1234/goodbye` will always match `/project/1234` first, and therefore I won't get any of the params passed through using the `useParams()` hook that react-router provides.

```
<Route
   path={['project/:context', 'project/:context/:hello?', 'project/:context/:goodbye?']}
   render={matchProps => <Project {...matchProps}/>}
/>
```

I could just have:

```
<Route
   path={'project/:context'}
   render={matchProps => <Project {...matchProps}/>}
/>
```

However, then when I use react-router's `useParams()` hook, I won't be able to interrogate the params `:goodbye` or `:hello`

Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this using React Router? Or do I just need to declare separate routes?

Comment: two ? is always a problem. you probably should try to write a route path with up to one ?. otherwise how does it know which one to match? i think u already answered your own question.

Comment: So if someone accessed your app at `/project/1234/goodbye`, what exactly do you want `useParams()` to yield? `{ goodbye: '????' }`?

Comment: @codemonkey This is a contrived example. But without adding the `:goodbye?` to the `path` prop in the the `<Route />` component, `useParams()` won't return _anything_ except `{ context: 1234 }`. So in this fake example, I would want `useParams()` should return `{ goodbye: 'goodbye' }`

Comment: @MaxMillington Yep. got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

This is an updated answer based on a better understanding of the requirements. It appears that you want `hello` and `goodbye` to actually be names of URL parameters so that you can grab them in the rendered component.

You have come pretty close to accomplishing this already.

In my example, I will use prameter name `var1` (instead of `hello` or `goodbye`) so that by accessing your app using `/project/1234/hello` you will get `{context: "1234", var1: "hello"}` and this URI `/project/1234/goodbye` will yield `{context: "1234", var1: "goodbye"}`

All you need is this Route:

```
<Route
      exact
      path={["/project/:context", "/project/:context/:var1"]}
      component={Project}
   />
```

Then in the rendered component, you can access the URL params like so:

```
props.match.params
```

> Similarly, this won't work, because using an array, /project/1234/goodbye will always match /project/1234 first, and therefore I won't get any of the params passed through using the useParams() hook that react-router provides.

You are absolutely correct, unless you use the `exact` param.

Here is a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-5-forked-1jjwt?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I'll update the question. You're right, I'll get the same component with all three routes. However, when I use react-router's `useParams()` hook, it  won't return the `{ hello: 'value', goodbye: 'value' }` params

Comment: @MaxMillington The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then you can just do:

```
<Route path="/project/:context">
    <Project />
</Route>
```

This is because you aren't calling exact path. Basically anything that starts with /project/:context will navigate to the correct component, even if you had 10 more parameters after it.

Comment: I'll update the question. You're right, I'll get the same component with all three routes. However, when I use react-router's `useParams()` hook, it  won't return the `{ hello: 'value', goodbye: 'value' }` params